# How to add reset functionality to a master-slave D-type flip-flop?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, reset

I'm trying to implement a shift register and therefore need values to be stored on the downwards edge of the clock signal (otherwise the whole register just sets to the input), so I am using a master-slave D-type flip-flop to store each bit. The design also requires a control line that resets the value stored in each flip-flop to 0 (low voltage) regardless of the clock value. How would I implement this by editing the below circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f99BRB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Any reason why you haven't used a DFF logic IC but have made it out of NAND gates instead? It would be straightforward to implement reset otherwise and you'd be making a simpler circuit.

Comment: @TonyM I'm not an electrical engineer, I'm a computer scientist! I need to use just logic gates for my circuit.

Comment: There's no difference between using a logic IC or using individual gates to get from point A to point B except that if you use a chip you'll have a lot less wiring - and the joys that go with it -  to contend with. :)

Comment: But you will have to make your circuit out of many more logic ICs than if you used a D-type flip-flop logic IC. Sorry, it seemed a fair question.

Comment: @EMFields For the coursework I'm doing I need to show the actual logic circuit, I'm not actually soldering anything together. If I was to do this in real life I would definitely wouldn't be using individual logic gates!

Comment: @TonyM see above comment :)

Comment: Are we just doing your computer science homework for you, then? I'm afraid that does defeat its object :-)

Comment: @TonyM No, this is an extension that I don't even need to do, but I was interested how to implement it :P

Comment: Good for you, to be encouraged :-) I did electronics at college and computer science at uni, found that they complemented each other well. Electronics design became the forte. Anyway, let me think about this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An asynchronous reset can be implemented by adding a third input to the lower NAND gate in each of the cross-coupled pairs in your diagram. Connect them together and drive this input low to reset the output; otherwise, drive it high.

BTW, it would have been easier to talk about the individual components of your diagram if you had left the reference designators on them.

Answer (score 1):

Paddding

Here's how TI does it:

[image]

Comment: That's how TI did it in a design entirely different than a conventional master-slave flip-flop. The SN7474 uses three S-R latches and is not a master-slave design. If one is into such things, it is quite interesting to analyze the three S-R design and see how it works; it's much less obvious than a conventional master-slave FF.